# How to enable only 3 months in AntD Range Picker?

Tags: datepicker, antd

I am using AntD Range Picker. I want to allow the user to select only 90 days, starting from 90 days from today. I have mange to block all the future days (after today)  with the following code. How can I allow only 3 months (3 months back from today)?

```
<RangePicker
            format="YYYY-MM-DD"
            onChange={onChange}
            disabled={loading}
            onOpenChange={onOpenChange}
            disabledDate={(currentDate) => currentDate.isAfter(moment())}
          />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
function disabledDate(current) {  
    return current > moment() || current < moment().subtract(3, 'day');
}

<DatePicker disabledDate={disabledDate} />
```

the  first condition will disable the future days and the second one will enable 3 dates backward from today. In your case, you can change it to 90.

[image: Edit]

Comment: @Chananderi  perfect solution

Answer (score 0):

### with Dayjs

```
const disabledDate = (current: Dayjs) => {
  const dayPastThreeDays = dayjs().subtract(3, "day");

  return current < dayPastThreeDays || current > dayjs();
}; 


<DatePicker.RangePicker format={"DD/MM/YY"} disabledDate={disabledDate} />
```

[image]

But if you want to include the 3rd day past today. You can modify the code as below

```
const disabledDate = (current: Dayjs) => {
  const dayPastThreeDays = dayjs().subtract(3, "day");

  return current < dayPastThreeDays.startOf("day") || current > dayjs();
};
```

[image]

[image: Edit antd-picker-disabled-dates]